# Why does 'The Wolf of Wall Street' contain so many nude scenes?

Tags: analysis, the-wolf-of-wall-street

Recently I watched 'The Wolf of Wall Street' and was quite disturbed by the many naked/nude scenes. They seemed a little unecessary to me, as they could as well have been shot as legs alone or similar instead of showing their entire sex process and their nude bodies. The same goes for the use of abusive language (like "f--k" and other strong adult words). But maybe I just don't see the further use this imagery and language had for the rest of the movie.

So my question is why those particular scenes are included? Is this a technique for marketing their movie or does it contribute to the rest of the movie's story and themes in any way? Is this a necessary part in the movie?

Comment: It was a movie about excesses, and excesses are shown. It was not a documentary. Maybe your expectations were wrong. If you want to avoid such there are databases you can query before watching a movie, and the rating gives a hint too. (The disgusting and disturbing part of the movie was their lack of morale and the system that allowed them to continue to"work", not the naked skin.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I'm not a mod so I don't know if this question is on-topic or not but it feels to me an unnecessary question as it appears to be based on the OP's feelings towards the usage of nudity and strong language in this film when 1) it's a scorcese film 2) it's an adult (18 rating in the UK) rated film 3) the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slj4-Sv-YNA) gives a clue as to what this film will be about 4) one could argue that everything is unnecessary when it boils down to it so it becomes an opinion based question are my thoughts

Comment: @EdChum Sure, the OP's moral compass might be a bit flawed and the premise of the question isn't the most objective. But the question itself in which way the excessive language and nudity contributed to the film is pretty much objectively answerable and of general interest for understanding the movie. I see that the question's wording and the asker's personal judgement makes this an oh too easy target for "primarily opinion-based", but the actual question isn't really.

Comment: I have tried to rephrase the question and tone down the moralist attitude a bit, concentrating on the valid and interesting question that's actually asked (without detracting from the original question too far, I hope).

Comment: I'm with Ed on this. Napoleon, there is no solid objective answer to this type of question. There's certainly plenty of good subjective answers, of course, but now it's a discussion rather than a Q/A. Also, from the OP's original post, it's clear that their intent is mostly puritanical in nature.

Comment: @DA Of course there is. You know what, "good subjective" answers are actually valid and good (neither are they "discussion" by themselves and I don't know how people always draw that connection). Never heard that "good subjective vs bad subjective" fuss that SE throws around now and then? And we're not judging the original post here either, I "repaired" it for a reason. It  simply doesn't matter what the asker *wanted* to ask or what his intentions are, only what the question *does* ask. We're at SE, it doesn't really matter what the asker *wants* to hear.

Comment: @Napoleon This sort of question can be asked about every aspect of every movie.  Anything can be questioned.  This question is *purely* subjective, not "good subjective", unless the director/producer/etc. happens to have put out a statement on this specific subject.  Any argument anyone else could make is exactly as valid as every other argument.  It turns into a poll and voting becomes a popularity contest instead of being based on accuracy, usefulness, or other appropriate metrics.

Comment: @MatthewRead That's why you have to base your subjective ramblings on the actual movie, so that it is an objectively reasoned good subjective answer and not just a subjective answer. It's the "why" that counts.

Comment: Personally, I find the topic intriguing. There's a lot of discussion of nudity in film, particularly discussing whether it's gratuitous or not. While the OP's puritanical (but culturally understandable) morals don't need to be the center of the question, I would argue that there's likely much discussion of this topic... specifically [interviews](http://screenrant.com/wolf-of-wall-street-controversy-martin-scorsese-response-video/) with crew (or even Scorsese himself) who may actually be able to give objective information.

Comment: Another source of information would be the [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_%28book%29) it's based on... apparently much of the content is described in detail, including [DiCaprio's character walking around naked with a lit candle in his rectum](http://variety.com/2014/film/news/schoonmaker-enjoys-long-collaboration-with-scorsese-1201032064/).

Comment: @Catija that is an interesting topic but I don't personally like such opinion questions myself and i do think that the impact on the viewer is entirely subjective, for instance I've seen far worse shocking scenes in films (Darth Vader's Calculon style *Nooooooo* in revenge of the sith) than those in this film but I wouldn't think that asking whether this is 1) shocking or not 2) was a marketing ploy or not 3) was a gimmick or not from the director. To me it's irrelevant, I either like a film/scene or I don't.

Comment: It would be a more interesting question to ask if Scorcese is a misogynist or if he glamourises violence

Comment: If this is not an opinion based question, then I would like to know 'what is'. OP not only questions the nude scenes, but also provides his own view on how it should be done : "they could as well have been shot as legs alone or similar instead of showing their entire sex process ". Well in the old bollywood movies, to imply a sex, they used to show 2 birds striking their beaks together and finally some boiling milk would spill out of utensil on stove. That's one way too. Should we ask the directors - why not this way ? Or should we ask the viewers if they would like this way?

Comment: I would also like to quote this question http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/why-is-daredevil-2015-so-brutal. This question too asks why it is so brutal, but it asks in reference with its predecessor, which is valid, but I don't see anything like that in this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much of these scenes never happened and the movie isn't similar at all with the book "The Wolf of Wall Street"; these scenes don't contribute at all in the main theme of the movie, which is the "[pump-dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_and_dump)" scheme Belfort did and the reason why they found it guilty at court. About why Scorsese made the sex, money wasting-style changes, Donnie Porush (in the movie is Donnie Azoff), Belfort's partner [said in a interview with Mother Jones](http://www.motherjones.com/media/2013/12/wolf-wall-street-martin-scorsese-jonah-hill-danny-porush-jordan-belfort):

> "Hey, it's Hollywood. I'm not a communist; **I know they want to make a movie that sells**. And Jordan wrote whatever he could to make the book sell. His greatest gift was always that of a self-promoter."

Some scenes are real, for example:

> Porush (Azoff) eating the golden fish:"I said to one of the brokers, *'If you don't do more business, I'm gonna eat your goldfish!'* So I did."

There is [an interview](http://et.tv/1mqsE5E) with the real Jordan Belfort about what is real and what is not. But, if you're interested to know deeper about the real and the fiction of the movie (if he was drogadict, they had sex in a pile of money) [History versus Hollywood](http://www.historyvshollywood.com/reelfaces/the-wolf-of-wall-street.php) made a great post about it with real photos of the Jordan Belfort.